# Next.js GetStaticPaths: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'getAllPostIds' before initialization

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am making a simple next js blog type of application using graphql as a data fetching backend to render text. Using `getStaticPaths`, I'm running into the following error when I try to fetch data for my page.

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'getAllPostIds' before initialization
```

Here is my code:

```
pages/posts/[id].tsx


import { getAllPostIds } from '../../../lib/posts'

const Post = ({ postData }) => {
   ... code.....
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const paths = getAllPostIds('aws');

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  }
}

export default Post;
```

And here is my `posts.ts` where I use graphql to fetch data.

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { GraphQLClient } from "graphql-request";

const GET_POST_IDS = gql`
  query($folder: String!) {
    repository(owner: "assembleinc", name: "documentation") {
      object(expression: $folder) {
        ... on Tree {
          entries {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`
;

const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient('https://api.github.com/graphql', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
  }
});

export const getAllPostIds = (folder: String) => {
  return useQuery(folder, async () => {
    ... fetch data ...
  });
}
```

Essentially, before I can even get the data through graphql, next js is complaining that `getAllPostIds` can't be initialized even though I import it at the top. Is there some next.js magic that I am not seeing?

Comment: You can't use the `useQuery` hook inside `getStaticProps` on the server-side. `useQuery` can only be called from within a React component on the client. For SSR usage of React Query in Next.js see https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr#using-nextjs.